# Deciding between two different GTX 980 TI

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I just ordered a EVGA GTX 980 TI SC+ AC2+ with Backplate.

It is slightly overclocked which is why I'm going for that version.

However as I was browsing around afterwards I found the MSI Gaming version of the GTX 980 TI. It seems to be a bit more overclocked, but also more expensive.

So I was wondering if the extra <100 mhz of overclocking would be enough to spend more money?

Though I'm guessing that with the EVGA version I would still be able to reach the same amount of OC with their Precision software so maybe its just a waste of extra money?

I'm a bit confused as to whether or not to cancel the current order and spend extra money for the MSI version (Money I could be spending on something else) or I should just stick with the EVGA.

There is also a higher delivery time on the MSI version which means I wont be getting it for the next two weeks.

Any opinions and help regarding the whole OC thing would be highly appreciated.

Links to each card

[EVGA](https://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=06G-P4-4995-KR)

[MSI](http://eu.msi.com/product/vga/GTX-980Ti-GAMING-6G.html#hero-overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the EVGA one. Here's why:

1. 'till now I never noticed 100 Mhz while gaming.
2. You'd have to run it in OC mode and you should consider the noise level(Though I have no experience, just consider it)
3. You could overclock it yourself, EVGA has an extreme good warranty (http://www.evga.com/support/faq/afmviewfaq.aspx?faqid=55)
4. EVGA also gives you EVGA PrecisionX which is (in my opinion) better then MSI Afterburner
5. EVGA warranty is 5 years
6. You wouldn't need 2 8pin conectos.. only 1x 8pin and 1 6pin (although power draw is the same)

I'm using and EVGA 780 ACX and I'm as happy as at the day I bought it (Jep, EVGA fanboy over here).

I hope this helps you a little, I wish you a lot of fun while building ;)